# Why is row count 0 in my PostgreSQL plan?

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have a query which is equi-joining two tables, TableA and TableB using a nested loop. Because of the "equi"-join contraint, all rows returned in the result will therefore correspond to at least one row from each of these two tables. However, according to the plan (EXPLAIN ANALYZE) the actual rows count is 0 from TableB, even though a row is returned in the final result. How can the *actual rows* count equal zero here?

Here is the execution plan:

```
=> explain analyze select p.id, p.title, s.count from products p, stock s where p.id = s.p_id and s.w_id = 6 and p.type = 9 and s.count > 0 order by p.title;
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=42.42..42.42 rows=2 width=36) (actual time=0.198..0.199 rows=1 loops=1)
   Sort Key: p.title
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..42.41 rows=2 width=36) (actual time=0.170..0.181 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on products p  (cost=0.00..9.25 rows=4 width=32) (actual time=0.068..0.106 rows=4 loops=1)
               Filter: (type = 9)
         ->  Index Scan using stock_pk on stock s  (cost=0.00..8.28 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=0 loops=4)
               Index Cond: ((w_id = 6) AND (p_id = p.id))
               Filter: (count > 0)
 Total runtime: 0.290 ms
```

And the two table definitions... The products table first:

```
=> \d products
           Table "public.products"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------+------------------------+-----------
 id     | integer                | not null
 title  | character varying(100) | 
 type   | integer                | 
 price  | double precision       | 
 filler | character(500)         | 
Indexes:
    "products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "products_type_idx" btree (type)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "orderline" CONSTRAINT "orderline_p_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES products(id)
    TABLE "stock" CONSTRAINT "stock_p_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES products(id)
```

The stock table:

```
=> \d stock
     Table "public.stock"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 w_id   | integer | not null
 p_id   | integer | not null
 count  | integer | 
Indexes:
    "stock_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (w_id, p_id)
    "stock_p_id_idx" btree (p_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "stock_p_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES products(id)
    "stock_w_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (w_id) REFERENCES warehouses(id)
```

Comment: Post the query and the explain plan please

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual rows of the inner index scan is the average number of rows returned in each call of it.

Looking at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html:

> In some query plans, it is possible for a subplan node to be executed more than once. For example, the inner index scan is executed once per outer row in the above nested-loop plan. In such cases, the loops value reports the total number of executions of the node, and the actual time and rows values shown are averages per-execution. This is done to make the numbers comparable with the way that the cost estimates are shown. Multiply by the loops value to get the total time actually spent in the node.

I'm not sure how it's rounded (I'm guessing down to the nearest int, after averaging), but it might be that most rows in `products` don't have a corresponding row in `stock`.